# What to choose for execution environment JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, desktop-application

I want to implement a java desktop-application using eclipse and when I click on new project I have to choose the JRE version (J2SE 1.2-1.5, JavaSE 1.6-1.8). My question is: what is the best version that I would choose? And if I decided to work with jre1.8.0 would other computers that support earlier JRE versions (e.g jre1.6) be able to run the application on their machines?

Comment: 1.6 might be your best choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you should use the newest version of Java for your development.

If your client is restricted to an older JRE, then you can set your compiler level. This is a separate setting from your JDK version (right click your project, go to properties, then Java compiler). Newer versions of Java can be set to create code that will work in older versions of Java.

Comment: Careful, there is one gotcha: You can still use newer API without the compiler complaining. The compiler level only influences syntactic checks.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking this question is that I implemented an application as a project and when my friend took it from me to run it on his computer it didn't run. He double clicked on the app but nothing happened. So I don't want to fall in the same mistake again.

Comment: @mhmdhsenkamal That doesn't necessarily mean that the Java version is the culprit. You need to run the jar via the command prompt to see what error your friend is getting. At this point it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest version. Every new version will support all the features of old version. I would go for jre 1.8.